# Who plays K's wife in the first Men in Black?

Tags: character, men-in-black

Who is the actress playing his ex love interest who K is looking at from a satellite camera on his computer monitor, and at the end of the film he ends up with her. When I first saw her I thought she looked very like the british actress Diane Keen but she isn't in the credits so I cannot be sure.

[image]

Comment: Actually, it was K, not J. I corrected that for ya.

Answer (score 5):

It's [Patricia McPherson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patricia_McPherson).

Couldn't find much about her role in the movie since it's a really small part, but in her [filmography](http://www.series-80.net/us/actor/filmography/patricia-mcpherson.html) it shows that she appeared in the movie as K's wife:

> Men in Black (1997) (uncredited) -    Elizabeth Ann Reston (K's wife)

Comment: Strangely, this role isn't listed on [her IMDb page](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0574253/#actress).

Comment: @Thunderforge I'm also not sure if it's her, found some websites saying it is, and others that doesn't list her, gotta check later...